# Regex pattern find x occurrences of char within group of y chars

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to use regex to find any group of 500 characters that contain at least 300 `1`'s that may or may not be separated by `0`'s

I tried using `[1]{500}` but it seems that only works when the `1`'s are directly next to each other.

example input

> 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

Comment: How many times do you want to find the characters, once or multiple times?

Comment: I would like to find all occurrences

Comment: So `111100...`, `11100...`, `1100...`, `100...`

Comment: Yes, as long as each of those groups still contain 300 `1`'s

Comment: Good to know, I expected the opposite to be true

Comment: You need something like this ? https://regex101.com/r/3lps6j/1/

Comment: Is this a yes/no question here?  That is, are you just asking whether _any_ such block exists?  Or, do you want to actually report all such matching blocks?

Comment: @CodeManiac That pattern will just substrings of 500 characters which begin with 1

Comment: @CertainPerformance how about this `(?:(?=.?1.?)){300}.{500}` ?   https://regex101.com/r/3lps6j/3/

Comment: @CodeManiac The lookaheads won't consume any characters, so the *repeated* lookaheads will always match the same characters, which won't do much - same issue, it'll match `10000000...` with no more 1s. I think `(?:(?=<something>)){n}` might never be useful, no matter what's in `<something>`

Comment: @CertainPerformance no it won't . check this https://regex101.com/r/fYEIKx/1/

Comment: @CodeManiac Put a 0 at the beginning of the input and it will pass, despite having only one `1`

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh i see. you're right mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
(?=.{500}(?=(.*$)))(?:0*1){300}.*(?=\1$)
```

you can: lookahead for the first 500 characters, then capture the rest of the string in the first group. Then with `(?:0*1){300}`, you match the next 300 `1`s in the string, and lookahead for the first group to ensure that the 300 matched `1`s come *within* those first 500 characters. The 500 characters you want as the result will be the full match.

But, this sort of thing is extremely inefficient - it takes *way* too many steps.

https://regex101.com/r/j8dCzT/1 (you may need to increase the timeout to see the matches)

I'm not sure if there's a better way with a regex, but if there isn't, it would be better to iterate over the string manually, counting the number of characters as you go.

Comment: I edited to remove the first capturing group, I realized it was unnecessary because the lookahead at the end ensures that all consumed matched characters will be equivalent to it.

Comment: Basically, you need a way to iterate over the beginning characters *twice*, once to match 500 characters, and again to make sure there are 300 `1`s contained in those 500 characters - that double-iteration can be done with a capture group inside a lookahead. At the end of the pattern, `(?=\1$)` ensures that the 300 `1`s that were just matched come within the 500 initial characters, otherwise the match will allow itself to expand indefinitely, which we don't want.